# При получении ответа php перезагрузить страницу (jquery.form)

Tags: jquery, php

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $('#auth').ajaxForm( {
        target: '#preview', 
        success: function() {           
            $('#auth').resetForm();
        } 
    });                 
});
```

Использую `jquery.form` для отправки формы. Далее получаю ответ, но если ответ к примеру `'noaccess'`, то перезагрузить страницу, а если такого ответа нет, то ничего не перезагружать. Как осуществить в данном случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте параметр функции `callback`

```
jQuery(function($)
  {
    $('#auth').ajaxForm( {
    target: '#preview', 
    success: function(data) {           
            if (data=='noauth') $('#auth').resetForm();
        } 
    });                 
 });
```